# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 Spring cloud gateway (Finchley.M5) and netflix eureka integration is not working

Tags: spring-cloud

I am trying to access the **/get** API or endpoint as defined in **application.yml** but I am getting 404 not found

GET /get HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8761
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.9

HTTP/1.1 404
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 10:39:07 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/get",
    "status": 404,
    "timestamp": "2018-01-23T10:39:07.770+0000"
}

Here is my setup

### Maven pom dependencies Finchley.M5

org.springframework.cloud:spring-boot-starter-actuator

org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server

org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway

org.springframework.cloud:spring-boot-starter-webflux

### application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: get
        uri: http://httpbin.org:80
        predicates:
        - Path=/get
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
```

### Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class GatewayApplication {

@Bean
public DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator clientRouteDefinitionLocator(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient) {
    return new DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator(discoveryClient);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

### Error Stack Trace

2018-01-23 15:33:14.687  INFO 14372 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6913c1fb: startup date [Tue Jan 23 15:33:14 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-23 15:33:14.903  INFO 14372 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-01-23 15:33:14.935  INFO 14372 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9f413f5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-23 15:33:15.120  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl      : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.

.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
 \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.0.0.M7)

2018-01-23 15:33:16.591  INFO 14372 --- [           main] com.example.gateway.GatewayApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-23 15:33:16.606  INFO 14372 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@339bf286: startup date [Tue Jan 23 15:33:16 IST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6913c1fb
2018-01-23 15:33:17.191  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'environmentWebEndpointExtension' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.env.EnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=environmentWebEndpointExtension; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/env/EnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.LifecycleMvcEndpointAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=environmentWebEndpointExtension; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/LifecycleMvcEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]]
2018-01-23 15:33:17.360  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=16d8c42e-7df4-3c80-b5a1-d892788f2f66
2018-01-23 15:33:17.376  INFO 14372 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-01-23 15:33:17.422  INFO 14372 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9f413f5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-23 15:33:17.476  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl      : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2018-01-23 15:33:17.639  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2018-01-23 15:33:17.639  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-01-23 15:33:17.639  INFO 14372 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2018-01-23 15:33:17.657  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\ncrdev\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\erl8.2\bin;C:\Users\sk185439\Downloads\rabbitmq_server-3.6.6\sbin;C:\Users\sk185439\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.7\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.7.1\5.7\msvc2013_64\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\NCR\AMS\bin;C:\Program Files\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SoftphoneSDK\;C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle\bin\;C:\Users\sk185439\Downloads\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.2.0.1.0\instantclient_12_2;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\sk185439\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\sk185439\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\sk185439\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\sk185439\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;.]
2018-01-23 15:33:17.761  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-01-23 15:33:17.761  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1155 ms
2018-01-23 15:33:18.239  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-01-23 15:33:18.239  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-01-23 15:33:18.262  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/application/gateway/routes/{id}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.actuate.GatewayWebfluxEndpoint.delete(java.lang.String)
2018-01-23 15:33:18.262  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/application/gateway/routes/{id}],methods=[POST]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.actuate.GatewayWebfluxEndpoint.save(java.lang.String,reactor.core.publisher.Mono)
2018-01-23 15:33:18.262  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/application/gateway/refresh],methods=[POST]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono org.springframework.cloud.gateway.actuate.GatewayWebfluxEndpoint.refresh()
2018-01-23 15:33:18.262  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/application/gateway/routes/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.actuate.GatewayWebfluxEndpoint.route(java.lang.String)
2018-01-23 15:33:18.262  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/application/gateway/routes],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.actuate.GatewayWebfluxEndpoint.routes()
2018-01-23 15:33:18.262  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/application/gateway/globalfilters],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.actuate.GatewayWebfluxEndpoint.globalfilters()
2018-01-23 15:33:18.262  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/application/gateway/routes/{id}/combinedfilters],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.actuate.GatewayWebfluxEndpoint.combinedfilters(java.lang.String)
2018-01-23 15:33:18.262  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/application/gateway/routefilters],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.actuate.GatewayWebfluxEndpoint.routefilers()
2018-01-23 15:33:18.293  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaController.status(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map)
2018-01-23 15:33:18.293  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/lastn],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaController.lastn(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map)
2018-01-23 15:33:18.324  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-23 15:33:18.324  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-23 15:33:18.340  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-01-23 15:33:19.815  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2018-01-23 15:33:21.164  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname
2018-01-23 15:33:21.471  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map)
2018-01-23 15:33:21.471  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map)
2018-01-23 15:33:21.471  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto private java.util.Map> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-01-23 15:33:21.502  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-23 15:33:21.502  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-23 15:33:21.502  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-23 15:33:21.502  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-23 15:33:21.502  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-23 15:33:21.502  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-01-23 15:33:21.502  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'servletContainer' to urls: [/eureka/*]
2018-01-23 15:33:21.502  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-01-23 15:33:21.549  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
2018-01-23 15:33:21.602  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-01-23 15:33:21.602  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2018-01-23 15:33:21.649  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2018-01-23 15:33:21.649  INFO 14372 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2018-01-23 15:33:21.949  WARN 14372 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-01-23 15:33:21.949  INFO 14372 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-01-23 15:33:21.967  WARN 14372 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-01-23 15:33:21.967  INFO 14372 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-01-23 15:33:21.987  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl      : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2018-01-23 15:33:22.071  INFO 14372 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@339bf286: startup date [Tue Jan 23 15:33:16 IST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6913c1fb
2018-01-23 15:33:22.187  WARN 14372 --- [           main] GatewayClassPathWarningAutoConfiguration :

---

Spring MVC found on classpath, which is incompatible with Spring Cloud Gateway at this time. Please remove spring-boot-starter-web dependency.

---

2018-01-23 15:33:22.819  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [After]
2018-01-23 15:33:22.819  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Before]
2018-01-23 15:33:22.819  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Between]
2018-01-23 15:33:22.819  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Cookie]
2018-01-23 15:33:22.819  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Header]
2018-01-23 15:33:22.819  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Host]
2018-01-23 15:33:22.819  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Method]
2018-01-23 15:33:22.819  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Path]
2018-01-23 15:33:22.834  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [Query]
2018-01-23 15:33:22.834  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.g.r.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator    : Loaded RoutePredicateFactory [RemoteAddr]
2018-01-23 15:33:22.871  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2018-01-23 15:33:22.888  INFO 14372 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2018-01-23 15:33:22.888  INFO 14372 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2018-01-23 15:33:22.888  INFO 14372 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1516701802888 with initial instances count: 0
2018-01-23 15:33:23.119  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.ui.freemarker.SpringTemplateLoader   : SpringTemplateLoader for FreeMarker: using resource loader [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@339bf286: startup date [Tue Jan 23 15:33:16 IST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6913c1fb] and template loader path [classpath:/templates/]
2018-01-23 15:33:23.119  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.v.f.FreeMarkerConfigurer         : ClassTemplateLoader for Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration
2018-01-23 15:33:23.273  INFO 14372 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initializing ...
2018-01-23 15:33:23.273  WARN 14372 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : The replica size seems to be empty. Check the route 53 DNS Registry
2018-01-23 15:33:23.288  INFO 14372 --- [           main] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Finished initializing remote region registries. All known remote regions: []
2018-01-23 15:33:23.288  INFO 14372 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initialized
2018-01-23 15:33:23.351  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-01-23 15:33:23.372  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-01-23 15:33:23.373  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-01-23 15:33:23.373  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-01-23 15:33:23.373  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2018-01-23 15:33:23.373  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2018-01-23 15:33:23.388  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=339bf286,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2018-01-23 15:33:23.420  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2018-01-23 15:33:23.420  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application gateway with eureka with status UP
2018-01-23 15:33:23.420  INFO 14372 --- [      Thread-39] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Setting the eureka configuration..
2018-01-23 15:33:23.420  INFO 14372 --- [      Thread-39] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Eureka data center value eureka.datacenter is not set, defaulting to default
2018-01-23 15:33:23.420  INFO 14372 --- [      Thread-39] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Eureka environment value eureka.environment is not set, defaulting to test
2018-01-23 15:33:23.435  INFO 14372 --- [      Thread-39] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : isAws returned false
2018-01-23 15:33:23.435  INFO 14372 --- [      Thread-39] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Initialized server context
2018-01-23 15:33:23.435  INFO 14372 --- [      Thread-39] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node
2018-01-23 15:33:23.435  INFO 14372 --- [      Thread-39] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Renew threshold is: 1
2018-01-23 15:33:23.435  INFO 14372 --- [      Thread-39] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Changing status to UP
2018-01-23 15:33:23.435  INFO 14372 --- [      Thread-39] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2018-01-23 15:33:23.470  INFO 14372 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http) with context path ''
2018-01-23 15:33:23.470  INFO 14372 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8761
2018-01-23 15:33:23.472  INFO 14372 --- [           main] com.example.gateway.GatewayApplication   : Started GatewayApplication in 10.557 seconds (JVM running for 11.312)
2018-01-23 15:33:41.250  INFO 14372 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-01-23 15:33:41.250  INFO 14372 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-01-23 15:33:41.265  INFO 14372 --- [nio-8761-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 15 ms

Comment: Can you please give more information?  What are your dependencies of your gateway app?

Comment: Dependencies (Finchley.M5)
-------------------
spring-boot-starter-actuator,
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server,
spring-cloud-starter-gateway,
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix,
spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive,
spring-boot-starter-webflux

--------------------------
I have enabled eureka server and using DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator for load balancing for routing.

Comment: Sample route
-----------------
route(r -> r
                        .path("/sample-service/**")
                        .rewritePath("/sample-service/(?<remaining>.*)", "/${remaining}")
                        .uri("lb://sample-service"))

Comment: put them in the issue, not in comments please

Comment: @spencergibb I have added the additional information. 
I am not sure if I can use single application which will serve as Eureka Server as well as spring cloud gateway for routing purpose.
Please let me know in case you need further information.

Answer (score 1):

According to your stack trace, this seems to be Root Cause of Netflix Eureka not registered on the cloud gateway.

> Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1 2018-01-23 15:33:22.888 INFO 14372 --- [ main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Client configured to neither register nor query for data. 2018-01-23 15:33:22.888 INFO 14372 --- [ main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1516701802888 with initial instances count: 0 2018-01-23 15:33:23.119 INFO 14372 --- [ main]

You should change some application properties in application.yml file:-

```
           eureka:
              client:
                fetch-registry: true
                register-with-eureka:false
                service-url:
                  defaultZone:htttp://eurekSever-xxx.com (eureka server url on the cloud)
```

In order for Client to either register or query for data ,you need to make one of fetch-registry or register-with eureka as true. You can make both as true. Let me explain what those fields mean here:

**fetch-registry** : true
(This property allows Client application to fetch registered service on the eureka server by locating the eureka server through eureka.client.serviceurl.defaultZone). Discovery Client checks whether it can fetch registered services on the eureka server. If this property is false,it is not able to query for data)

**register-with-eureka**:true
(Client application(App A) use this property if they want to be registered on the eureka server with particular instance which can later be fetched by another client application say App B).

discoveryClient.getInstances("client-application-name").get(0).getURI() should get the url of first Instance registered on netflix eureka